# Showing that $J(W) = || S w || - \frac{1}{2} w^T S w$ is maximized only when $||w| = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

An exercise I encountered during my studies asks me to proof the following:
Given a scatter matrix $S= XX^T$, $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ and a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^d$, the reader is asked to show that a necessary condition for
$$ J(w) = || Sw || -\frac{1}{2} \cdot w^T S w$$
to be maximized is that $w$ is a unit vector.

To solve the exercise, I calculated the derivative w.r.t $w$ and set it to zero.

$$\frac{\partial J(w)}{\partial w} = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial J(w)}{\partial w} = \frac{Sw^T}{ \|{Sw}\|} \cdot S - w^T \cdot S$$
$$\frac{Sw^T\cdot S}{ \|{Sw}\|}  - w^T \cdot S = 0$$

My guess is that this property only holds if $||w|| = 1$. However, I don't see a way how to show this.

Am I on the right track? If so, how could I complete the proof?

Answer (score 1):

The optimality condition is
$$
\frac1{\|Sw\|}S^2w - Sw=0.
$$
If $S$ is injective (or equivalently $X^T$ is injective) then this implies
$$
\frac1{\|Sw\|}Sw - w=0,
$$
which is the claim.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Where exactly are you using that $||w|| = 1$ here?

Comment: I showed that every non-zero maximizer has norm one.